# Laravel 4.2 upload file success but not found when I used it

Tags: php, laravel, upload

Laravel 4.2 upload file success but not found when I used it

The file uploaded succesfully on the directory I've been specified, but when I want to display it, it return not found, but if I change it to other file name in the same directory, it appears. What's wrong?

here is my code:

***app/services/CommonProvider.php***

```
<?php
class CommonProvider{
    # simple class to provide static common functions

    public static function uploadFiles($filename,$name,$location = 'img/'){     
        if(Input::hasFile($name)){
            $filename .= '.'.Input::file($name)->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $location . $filename;
            if(Input::file($name)->move($location, $filename))
                return $filename;               
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here is the ***updateUser*** method (for example) from ***app/services/UserProvider.php***

```
public function updateUser($input, $user_id) {
        $validation_messages = $this->validateUser(Input::all(), false);
        if ($validation_messages !== true) return $validation_messages;

        try {

            $insert = $this->user->find($user_id);
            $insert->access_level = $input['access_level'];
            $insert->email = $input['email'];
            $insert->name = $input['name'];
            $insert->mobile_no = $input['mobile_no'];
            if ($input['password'] != '') $insert->password = Hash::make($input['password']);
            if (!isset($input['active_status'])) $insert->active_status = 0;
            $insert->save();

            $filename = CommonProvider::uploadFiles($insert->id, 'user_image', 'img/user_images/');

            if ($filename) {
                $insert->user_image = $filename;
            }
            $insert->save();

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What do I miss?

Comment: what is your image view code ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add path to your filename when moving the file (you can add it when you want to retrieve the file).

```
$filename = $location . $filename;  // remove this line
```

And I think you need to add absolute path so you will know exactly where the uploaded file is moved to.

In this code I added `public_path()`

```
$abslocation = public_path() . '/'. $location;
if(Input::file($name)->move($abslocation, $filename))
   return $location . $filename;
```